# Same code, different results in Fiddle vs. VS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012

I'm a bit puzzled by differing results produced by [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bhL6nbas/) and by Visual Studio 2012. As can be seen in the fiddle, the output is showing "Ninja", and "Forever!". However, shouldn't I also see "power!" as part of the output?

Here's the VS code snippet in its entirety:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test Suite</title>
    <script type="text/script">
        function assert(value, desc) {
            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.className = value ? "pass" : "fail";
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc));
            document.getElementById("results").appendChild(li);
        }
        window.onload = function() { assert(true, 'power!'); };

        var ninja = {
            shout: function() {
                assert(true, 'Ninja');
            }
        };
        ninja.shout();

        setTimeout(
            function() { assert(true, 'Forever!'); },
            500);
    </script>
    <style>
        #results li.pass {
            color: green;
        }
        #results li.fail {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="results"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the above code I see ONLY the "power!" being printed, but then I run into the following error:

> *Unable to get property 'appendChild' of undefined or null reference*

And the error points to the last line of the `assert` function. Now, I know what the error means. I just don't see why the error is thrown.

As far as I can tell, I'm dealing with two semantically identical sets of code. Or am I? I am trying to figure out 1) why I don't see the "power!" output in my fiddle, and 2) why my VS code produces a different result, and 3) why the two results differ over the same code.

Comment: This is because on jsFiddle you have by default the option `onLoad` for the javascript code, which means that your code is already executed once the document is loaded. If you try to change that value to `onDoamready` you should also get the value **power!**. While for the VS version I guess that it tries to execute your code before properly loading the whole document which results in your error. Try putting all the code inside your window.onload function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bu default JSFiddle wraps JavaScript in an `onload` event handler…

[image: JSFiddle screenshot]

… your code also sets an `onload` handler:

```
window.onload = function() { assert(true, 'power!'); };
```

… but the document only loads once. By the time you assign that handler, the event has already passed.

---

And then the reverse is the problem when you run without JSFiddle.

`ninja.shout();` isn't inside a load event handler, and appears before `<ul id="results"></ul>` so it tries to `document.getElementById("results").appendChild(li);` before the results element exists in the DOM.

Comment: @Quentin - Makes perfect sense!